# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './stage.js'

Tags: module, vuex

Here, I have setup the laravel 6 project with vue and vuetify to create a crud table but for some reason I am not able to import vueX to my vue component.

Error:

> ERROR in ./resources/js/store/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve './stage.js' in 'c:\WinNMP\WWW\chillibiz\resources\js\store' 
>   @ ./resources/js/store/index.js 3:0-35 7:11-16  @
>   ./resources/js/app.js  @ multi ./resources/js/app.js
>   ./resources/sass/app.scss

stage.js

```
export default  {
        state: {
          stages: []
        },
        mutations: {
            ADD_STAGE(state, stage) {
                state.stages.push({
                    id: this.getters.newStageId,
                    code: stage.code,
                    name: stage.name,
                    description: stage.description

                });
            },
            UPDATE_STAGE(state, payload){
                state.stages = state.stages.map(stage => {
                    if (stage.id === payload.id) {
                        return Object.assign({}, stage, payload)
                    }
                    return stage;
                })
            },
            REMOVE_STAGE(state, stage){
                var stages = state.stages;
                var id = stage.id;
                var index = state.stages.findIndex(stage => stage.id == id)
                stages.splice(index, 1);
            },
        },
        actions: {
            getStage({commit}, stage){
                commit('GET_STAGE', stage)
            },
            addStage({commit}, stage){
                commit('ADD_STAGE', stage)
            },
            updateStage({commit}, payload){
                commit('UPDATE_STAGE', payload)
            },
            removeStage({commit}, stage){
                commit('REMOVE_STAGE', stage)
            },
        },
        getters: {
          stages: state => state.stages,
          newStageId(state) {  return state.stages.length > 0 ? state.stages[state.stages.length-1].id + 1 : 1; },
        }
    }
```

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import {stage} from './modules/stage.js';


Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
   stage
  },
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {}
});
```

Comment: Is stage.js in the same directory as your index.js?
Maybe try export default { instead of export const stage = {

Comment: @coedycode stage.js is in store/modules/stage.js and index.js is in store/index.js

Comment: In that case, I think you need to use 
import {stage}  from './modules/stage.js';

Comment: @coedycode It's still not working.

Comment: in stage.js have you change the start to
export default {

Comment: @coedycode Yes I have change ....you can see my stage.js file above.

Comment: your index.js is still showing

import {stage}  from './stage.js';

it needs to be

import {stage}  from './modules/stage.js';